# Ruby on Rails: how to render a string as HTML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have

```
@str = "<b>Hi</b>"
```

and in my erb view:

```
<%= @str %>
```

What will display on the page is: `<b>Hi</b>` when what I really want is **Hi**. What's the ruby way to "interpret" a string as HTML markup?

---

**Edit**: the case where

```
@str = "<span class=\"classname\">hello</span>"
```

If in my view I do

```
<%raw @str %>
```

The HTML source code is `<span class=\"classname\">hello</span`> where what I really want is `<span class="classname">hello</span>` (without the backslashes that were escaping the double quotes). What's the best way to "unescape" those double quotes?

Comment: You might also consider using the %Q[] syntax for string escaping.
e.g  



`%Q["quotation marks"] => "\"quotation marks\""`

Source:  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation


Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 368, accepted):

#### UPDATE

For security reasons, it is recommended to use [`sanitize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) instead of [`html_safe`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe).

```
<%= sanitize @str %>
```

---

What's happening is that, as a security measure, Rails is escaping your string for you because it might have malicious code embedded in it. But if you tell Rails that your string is `html_safe`, it'll pass it right through.

```
@str = "<b>Hi</b>".html_safe
<%= @str %>
```

OR

```
@str = "<b>Hi</b>"
<%= @str.html_safe %>
```

Using `raw` works fine, but all it's doing is converting the string to a string, and then calling `html_safe`. When I know I have a string, I prefer calling `html_safe` directly, because it skips an unnecessary step and makes clearer what's going on. Details about string-escaping and XSS protection are in [this Asciicast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3).

Comment: Fantastic. I could not find how to do that even after searching for an hour. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I've always used `raw`. Very glad to know about this!

Comment: Giving hanks from the future =)

Comment: sanitize is removed according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575106/undefined-method-sanitize-for-activerecordbase

Answer (score 23):

Use [raw](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw):

```
<%=raw @str >
```

But as @jmort253 correctly says, consider where the HTML really belongs.

Comment: Hi, this solution works, except with one caveat: please see edited question

Answer (score 19):

If you're on `rails` which utilizes [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/) — the shortest way to do it is

```
<%== @str >
```

Note the double equal sign. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13142326/535406) related question on SO for more info.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `simple_format(@str)` which removes malicious code.  Read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Answer (score 7):

You are mixing your business logic with your content.  Instead, I'd recommend sending the data to your page and then using something like JQuery to place the data where you need it to go.

This has the advantage of keeping all your HTML in the HTML pages where it belongs so your web designers can modify the HTML later without having to pour through server side code.

Or if you're not wanting to use JavaScript, you could try this:

```
@str = "Hi"

<b><%= @str ></b>
```

At least this way your HTML is in the HTML page where it belongs.

Comment: The problem is, my app is taking in a file that is poorly marked up, and "translating" it via regexes to good HTML markup to send to the view. Therefore, the HTML markup that is being generated is dynamic, so I can't know a priori which tags that are supposed to surround @str.

Where would I perform this "translation" work, if not in the models? I thought we weren't supposed to have extensive logic code in the views.

Comment: It's really a matter of opinion.  When developing a fresh app I prefer to keep everything as clean as possible.  But oftentimes we must work within the constraints of what others have left us with.  If your datasource returns HTML markup then perhaps take a look at using "raw" as described in Michael Stum's solution.

Comment: If you have inherited support of some code, and the code has areas that show poor thinking or design, then it really is part of your responsibility to clean it up to make it more maintainable. Leaving it as you found it is fine when it's great code to begin with, but leaving it better than you found it is good when it needed work. Part of my job is managing some legacy apps; I'm a fan of not fixing things that are not broken, but they couldn't be enhanced easily because of how they were written. I had to rewrite most of the function calls but it's SO much easier to work with now.

Comment: You shouldn't be using JavaScript for your HTML interpolation if there's no other reason to use JS. That will break your site for non-JS browsers (yes, there *are* some).

Comment: The html belongs in helpers too, and good forbids, in the database sometimes. Although I much rather storing markdown and then rendering to html.

Comment: @Macario - Hi, I'm not sure I fully understand your comment. Do you mind elaborating? Thank you!

Comment: Well sometimes html is generated outside the template in a helper function an needs not to be escaped, or sometimes, -allthough in my opinion is a bad practice and not pretty- it is generated by the user by a WYSIWG editor and stored in the database as html and also needs not to be escaped, off course it would need to be sanitized or bad things can happen. I prefer the templating language Markdown for letting the user input styled content. In that case you don't want your content to be escaped `<%= str.html_safe %>` is the way.

Comment: Off course if you allow non escaped content the resposabitily of ensuring non evil markup is up to you.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can try **CGI.unescapeHTML** method.

```
CGI.unescapeHTML "&lt;p&gt;This is a Paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;"
=> "<p>This is a Paragraph.</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are translating, and picking out your wanted code from a person's crappy coded file, could you use content_tag, in combo with your regex's.

Stealing from the api docs, you could interpolate this translated code into a `content_tag` like:

```
<%= content_tag translated_tag_type.to_sym, :class => "#{translated_class}" do -%>
<%= translated_text %>
<% end -%>
# => <div class="strong">Hello world!</div>
```

Not knowing your code, this kind of thinking will make sure your translated code is too compliant.

Comment: I'm assuming translated_text is the actual content within the div, right? ie, in the example, it'd be "Hello world!"? What if translated_text has more HTML in it, ie nested divs or spans? Would I have to call content_tag many times then?

Comment: and... sorry hit enter early...  each nested div/span inside is still a content_tag and you still need to validate it though right?  Since we can't see what you are doing with your fancy translating ;-), I'd assume you look for ALL tags, regardless if the regex is on the 'parent' of the html... such as <ul>.  you wouldn't put all li's as a big ass string to print would you?  each one would be it's own content_tag :li, text correct?

Answer (score 0):

> `@str = "<span class=\"classname\">hello</span>"`
>   If in my view I do
>
> `<%raw @str %>`
>   The HTML source code is `<span class=\"classname\">hello</span>` where what I really want is `<span class="classname">hello</span>` (without the backslashes that were escaping the double >quotes). What's the best way to "unescape" those double quotes?

Solution: use double quotes inside of single quotes (or single inside of double) to avoid escaping with a backslash.

```
@str = '<span class="classname">hello</span>'
<%raw @str %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The html_safe version works well in Rails 4...

```
<%= "<center style=\"color: green; font-size: 1.1em\" > Administrators only </center>".html_safe if current_user.admin? %
>
```