# Autocomplete in rails format data and display in a beautiful way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I use rails 3.2.2 and autocomplete, I m selecting customer by name and formatting it in a following way
format.json  { render :json => @customers.map{ |c| "#{c.name}:#{c.phone1}:#{c.email}" }  }

so, i need to parse json properly an display in a way i want for example 
I want write name in  but make font smaller and bold   ,display it in different color.
How i can achieve that?

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 416px; left: 0px; display: none; width: 419px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Adele Brekke:1-244-712-4421 x313:christophe@kuhlmanborer.net</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Madeline O'Conner Sr.:486-349-1046 x6765:kareem@hills.net</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

may be this works for you,

```
format.json { render :json => @customers.map{ |c| "#{c.name}:<span style='font-size:smaller;color:red'>#{c.phone1}</span>:#{c.email}" } }
```

Comment: where i should parsae it? I have Bryce Weber V:<span style='font-size:smaller;color:red'>(555)800-2490 x7097</span>:kyler@nienow.biz  now in my list.

Comment: jQuery ->
  $('#product_customer_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#product_customer_name').data('autocomplete-source') this is my products.js.coffe

Comment: When i type its appear like text: <h3> 'AAAAAAA' </h3> : <span style='font-size:5px;color:red'></span>:sa@gmail.com

Comment: yes, it is because when its render its convert HTML to STRING, you need to find a way to convert STRING to HTML at time of display on page using something like `html_safe` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576932/ruby-on-rails-how-to-render-a-string-as-html)

Comment: I got it:) but where should i do it? Inside the coffee script or at the render stage? Thanks

Comment: I don't know whether you can able to add ruby code inside coffee script or not, I guess html_safe will work at the time of displaying data.

Comment: format.json { render :json => @customers.map{ |c| " <h3> '#{c.name}' </h3> : <span style='font-size:5px;color:red'>#{c.phone1}</span>:#{c.email}".html_safe} }   is not working for me in that way .

Comment: Its getting quite complected to achieve your goal, could you please share your javascript code?