# What does <%== %> do in rails erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I saw this recently, thought it was interesting.  But I don't really understand what it does?

Ex.  I have a rails app and I want to bootstrap some json, so that I don't have to make a second request.  Normally I would write something like this.

`<%= raw @model.to_json %>`
or
`<%= @model.to_json.html_safe %>`

I have to send the message `raw` or `html_safe` or the json will be html escaped and thus not parsed correctly.  However, this seems to work too.

`<%== @model.to_json %>`

But I can't find any documentation.

Does anyone know what this does exactly?  i.e.  Is it the exact same as calling `html_safe` or `raw`?  Or is there more to it?

Comment: it's not a duplicate of the above, at all. I've never seen <%== btw so it's nice to learn something new .. good question.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`<%==` is equivalent to `raw`.

From the [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#output-safety):

> To insert something verbatim use the `raw` helper rather than calling
>   `html_safe`:
>
> ```
> <%= raw @cms.current_template %> <%# inserts @cms.current_template as is %>
> ```
>
> or, equivalently, use `<%==`:
>
> ```
> <%== @cms.current_template %> <%# inserts @cms.current_template as is %>
> ```

Comment: Looked at the rails guides, don't know how I missed that?  Thanks!

Comment: can this be used in interpolation? `"#{@something}  <p>Is here</p>"`  or would you just use html_safe at the end of the string?

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's really hard to google for this since google seems to strip those characters out and oddly there's many guides and wikipedia articles that have no mention of `<%== %>`

Answer (score 12):

Rails actually uses [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/) instead of ERB, which supports a variety of other stuff.

`<%==` is exactly as you expect, though: [It emits the value unescaped](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.03.html#escape-enhancer)

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb#L59

Comment: If you add something to address my original question, "Is it the exact same as calling html_safe or raw? Or is there more to it?".  I will accept this as an answer.  When I first read this I thought "awesome", and almost accepted it then.

Comment: I guess its not exactly the same, as its code in Erubis, versus the html_safe/raw methods which are implemented elsewhere (rails?).  Its goal is to make it easier to embed stuff 'as is'.  I agree its not documented well - was going to post the same question myself when I found this one.  PS The accepted answer is also correct too :)