# ruby on rails qr code implemetation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, qr-code

hi just trying to create a qr code in my rails website using sam vincents qr code generator https://github.com/samvincent/rqrcode-rails3....... first i added this code to a controller

> class QrcodeController < ApplicationController
>
> def qrcode 
>      respond_to do |format|
>        format.html
>      format.svg  { render:qrcode => @qrurl, :level => :l, :unit => 10, :color => black }
>       format.png  { render :qrcode => @qrurl } 
>        format.gif  { render :qrcode => @qrurl } 
>         format.jpeg { render :qrcode => @qrurl } 
>          end 
>           end
>
> ```
>    def options 
>      {:qrcode => "http://helloworld.com", size => 4} 
>       end
> ```
>
> end

then i am not sure what to add in the view i tried this

```
<div class="Qrcode qr">
<h2>Qr code</h2>

<p><%= link_to "SVG",  Qrcode_path("svg")  %></p>
<p><%= link_to "PNG",  Qrcode_path("png")  %></p>
<p><%= link_to "JPEG", Qrcode_path("jpeg") %></p>
<p><%= link_to "GIF",  Qrcode_path("gif")  %></p>
```

would appreciate any help on how it works as their are not that many instructions online
im using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 4.0.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using [rqrcode](http://whomwah.github.io/rqrcode/) gem. It's pretty simple and you don't need to generate images for your qrcodes. The code is generated using tables and some css styles...

You can use this helper: **/helpers/qrcode_helper.rb**

```
module QrcodeHelper
  require 'rqrcode'

  def render_qr_code text, size = 3
    return if text.to_s.empty?
    qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(text)
    sizeStyle = "width: #{size}px; height: #{size}px;"

    content_tag :table, class: "qrcode pull-right" do
      qr.modules.each_index do |x|
        concat(content_tag(:tr) do
          qr.modules.each_index do |y|
            color = qr.dark?(x, y) ? 'black' : 'white'
            concat content_tag(:td, nil, class: color, style: sizeStyle)
          end
        end)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Into your view **some_view.html.erb**

```
<%= render_qr_code("MYCODE") %>
```

And you need to add style for your code **qrcode.css.less**

```
table.qrcode {
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: #0000ff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;

  td {
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: #0000ff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;

    &.black {
      background-color: #000 !important
    }

    &.white {
      background-color: #fff !important
    }
  }
}
```

My example it's working with Rails 3.

Comment: I've been doing similar. One issue: When I print/save the page, thin white border lines show up between the modules... maybe just my PDF viewer

Comment: also worth noting that this is a common problem with rqrcode when you have longer text to encode https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode/issues/15

Comment: But where do you add the code in your view to display a .png?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example that avoids the need to write code to render each (x,y) "pixel" yourself.

In your controller:

```
def show
    @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new('https://stackoverflow.com/')
end
```

And then in your corresponding .html.erb view:

```
<p>
    <%== @qr.as_svg %>
</p>
```

(Note that this uses [`<%==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142326/what-does-do-in-rails-erb), not `<%=`; if you use the latter, you'll get the raw SVG XML source instead of a rendered SVG image.)

See the [RQRCode docs](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode/blob/master/README.md) for options that can be passed to `.as_svg`, and for other output options such as PNG.