# cant translate html code in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im new for ruby on rails. i have 3 question

1. how to i translate the html code

in controllers i set

```
def index
  @sentence = "Halo<br>worlds";
end
```

in index.html.erb display i set

```
<%= @sentence %>
```

but display

```
Halo<br>world
```

how do i make it like this

```
halo
world
```

2. how do i set onclick in submit button? i already tried set the button like this <%= submit_tag "back", onclick: "window.history.back();" %>

but the result is not go to previous page. but excetude the form..

3. how i can make an validation form if the validation code is in controllers. not in model

Comment: Technically you can use `html_safe` e.g. `<%= @sentence.html_safe %>` but I would not recommend this as marking strings as html safe can lead to code injection depending on how you are utilizing this. Sidenote: the proper break tag should be `<br />`. As for the other questions these are really 3 **very** separate questions (rails rendering, javascript, and server side code) and I would recommend doing a little research and then if you still cannot figure it our come back and ask them as separate questions.

Comment: I tested your question 2 on Rails 5.1, and it works as it's supposed to (browser goes back). Could be a browser issue. You should post it as a separate question. Don't write more than one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails automatically escapes all HTML in ERB templates. To prevent this escaping you can use the Rails ERB extension `<%== %>`. So in your case it would be:

```
<%== @sentence %>
```

See this question for some further discussion:
[What does <%== %> do in rails erb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142326/what-does-do-in-rails-erb)

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about `<%==` (although honestly now that I do it terrifies me :)) I would certainly prefer the explict nature of `raw` or `html_safe` over this little gem, but thank you for teaching me something.

Comment: True. It's a good idea to point out that it's potentially unsafe to use any of the unescaping methods in your templates. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<%= @sentence %>` with below content for a simple solution.

```
<% @sentence.split("<br/>").each do |word| %>
 <%= word %><br/>
<% end %>
```

for the second qsn, check the validations in validateform() function and then respond with true or false accordingly.

```
<%= button_to_function "Submit", "validateform()" %>
```