# What is the difference between <%== %> and <%= %> in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently, I decided to try a new gem for pagination and noticed quite an intresting construction:

```
<%== pagy_nav(@pagy) %>
```

I'd be prone to think it's a typo, but it repeats further:

```
<%== render partial: 'pagy/nav', locals: {pagy: @pagy} %>
```

Tried to google it with no result.

Comment: After a bit of looking around I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails#comment15090510_7996827) comment which asks the same question. The answer is *"The double equal means that the string is not escaped, as in raw."* - [Richard_G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails#comment34435273_7996827)

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142326/what-does-do-in-rails-erb

Comment: Yes, it's duplicate. I'm sorry!

Comment: @AlexanderGorg No need to excuse yourself, `<%==` is search term that doesn't produce a lot of results.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, thanks a lot! I'll add symbolhound to favs!