# Why the content display code html without render it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, markitup

I have used [MarkiItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/) to build a jquery editor. Now when user type content in textarea with html code, like this:

`A new <strong>true</strong> question`

When record was saved, it save `A new <strong>true</strong> question`. And when it display on page, it also display like content was saved, is `A new <strong>true</strong> question` . But i want the content display on web like this:

A new **true** question

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display it, use `html_safe`. This way your string would be rendered as HTML.
Refer to this question for more info.
[Ruby on Rails: how to render a string as HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576932/ruby-on-rails-how-to-render-a-string-as-html)