# Embed hyperlink in ruby string property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to “embed” a link in an object property, such as `deal.description = "Click <a href='www.something.com'>here!</a>"`.

Doing it that way doesn’t seem to work; my show page just shows all that text (with the html tag and everything).

Trying to use `#{link_to 'text', 'url'}` gives `NoMethodError: undefined method 'link_to' for main:Object`.

This is currently in my `seeds.rb` file but I'll also need to somehow allow my users to enter a link inside the `description` on the `new` page.

How do I do this?

Comment: In the rails console, what does `puts deal.description` display ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: how to render a string as HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576932/ruby-on-rails-how-to-render-a-string-as-html)

Comment: @LolWalid `You can check out the calendar <a href='http://mail01.tinyletterapp.com/FaresYouCanUse/today-s-flights-iowa-new-hampshire-south-carolina-nevada/13473421-www.google.com/flights?c=cf040a38-8c96-4f9b-9338-8c223c053a53'>here</a>.`

Comment: Look at my second comment, it should help you !

Comment: The second comment was exactly what I needed, thank you!